# How to remove the white border "halo" from my logo?

Tags: gimp, logo, inkscape, transparency

I have the original .ai files as I paid a graphic artist to do these logos. I uploaded a .gif export of the files only to see that they have a white border:

[image]

If I don't have AI/PS can I use something like GIMP or Inkscape to remove that with the AI file?

Comment: Hi! Do you only have the .ai file? Can you ask your designer to send you the logo in a different format, such as .eps? The white border is because all gifs use a 'background' color, or matte. How did you produce the gif? If you could export it as png instead, you wouldn't see the border.

Comment: I have all formats as well; I just figured .ai would be most relevant. I have .eps too.

Comment: I produced the gif by asking him to export it in AI for web devices. He then exported as gif.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your logo shows a white border around the color because of the format it was saved in. All `GIF` will use a matte color around them to blend them better to a background. Unfortunately, this means you usually need to know the background color you'll be using.

Since you have this available in different formats, I suggest you start by saving the icon as `PNG`. This should get rid of the border.

About the formats, you can open the logo using **[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/)**, a free, open source vector graphics program.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll give this a shot, I had been saving it as GIF format repeatedly assuming different things would fix it. However I will attempt to do PNG with Inkscape; do you know if just hitting "Save As" and selecting PNG will do the trick on my .eps/.ai files or do I need to do some export step?

Comment: You can use "Save As", yes. This might help: http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Save_as_vs_export